# Secrets as password format in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, aws-parameter-store

We are saving Secrets, keys in AWS secrets Manager and These can be retrieved later in programming. We can also define IAM policies who can access these values. We are able to see Keys and values combinations. For example I can save "AppPass=@123tx56tX". Admin user can see "AppPass" actual value, Is there any way it can be stored like secret "AppPass=**********" or any other AWS services, or any workaround. Just don`t want everyone (Who has access) to see the password values from Console.

Comment: So you want to grant people permission to see the secret but then hide it from them?

Comment: I want to save as "*********" format

Comment: Doesn't  'We can also define IAM policies who can access these values' solve the problem ? - ' Just don`t want everyone (Who has access) to see the password values from Console.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot

secret manager store a document (as text), but its not responsible of the format (could be XML, JSON, or anything)

If you want to show what's the format of the secret without show the value, maybe do it in description. But most of the time, the developer that'll use the secret have to know it (or at least a mock with a similar structure)

So either you can read the secret or you cannot, but you cannot access only a part of it

Comment: Yes look like we can not

Answer (score 0):

If you want encryption different from AWS provides (KMS), you will need to use a custom encryption code.

Comment: Can I use AWS KMS to encrypt values in secret manager and how?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can encrypt your data with KMS using AWS CLI or the newest aws-encryption-cli.

AWS CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/kms/encrypt.html#examples

AWS-ENCRYPTION-CLI: https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/security/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-your-data-with-the-aws-encryption-cli/